# Where to enable Drive service in the admin console?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace

In my Apps Script project, I'm trying to loop through folders in My Unit using `DriveApp.getFolders()`.  When the code reaches `while(folders.hasNext())`, I get the following error:

> "The feature you are attempting to use has been disabled by your domain administrator."

However, Google Drive service is enabled for all users on the domain.

Is there another security setting I need to ask the domain admin to enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable "Drive Apps" as well.

[image: Admin Console setting]

Comment: That option will allow users on the domain to install apps from the chrome store, right?  our admin does not want to allow that for security reasons.  Would be nice to separate the two, one setting to allow apps scripts & app engine apps that are built in-house & another one for opening up 3rd party apps.